# Bessel functions of matrix argument in the scalar case

Tags: special-functions, bessel-functions

Herz (1955) provides the following equality:
$$
A_\delta(-\lambda) - A_\delta(-\lambda)\lambda^{-\delta} = -\sin(\pi\delta)B_\delta(\lambda)/\pi
$$
where $A_\delta$ and $B_\delta$ are the [Bessel functions of matrix argument](https://dlmf.nist.gov/35.5) of first type and second type, in the case when the matrices are $1\times 1$.

However the left member is zero for $\lambda=1$, but not the right member. Is there something wrong in this equality? What is the error?

Comment: Since it is for $1\times1$ matrices, that is, scalars, couldn't each term ($A_\delta$, $B_\delta$) be written without Bessel functions of matrix arguments?

Comment: @username No idea. In the paper they are defined for matrices only (if I correctly remember, not sure... but almost sure). But would it change something?

Comment: Well you say that this identity holds for 1x1 "matrices". But in that case, the complicated notations for Bessel Functions of matrix argument simplify greatly since tr(X)=X, |k|=k etc...all in all it becomes normal Gamma functions and normal factorials. With any luck, if the notations are consistent, $A$ will become $J$ and $B$ will become $Y$ (or another natural pair of non matrix argument Bessel functions) and then you can just look up what the corresponding identity is in the DLMF.

Comment: @username I didn't know (or didn't remember) that $A$ -> $J$ and $B$ -> $Y$. Thanks. Will take a look at DLMF.